# How to choose date interval from pandas dataframe column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How to create a new dataframe based on date interval from an existing dataframe:

```
df=pd.DataFrame([["01.01.18",32],
    ["01.01.18",8],
    ["01.01.18",12],
    ["01.01.18",77],
    ["02.01.18",99],
    ["03.01.18",78],
    ["04.01.18",89],
    ["02.02.18",85],
    ["10.03.18",35],
    ["13.04.18",81],
    ["03.02.18",97],
    ["29.03.18",90],
    ["08.04.18",7]],columns=["date","payment"])
```

How do I create a dataframe with date values between 01.01.18 and 31.01.18, so the new df would look like:

```
Date Payment 
01.01.18,   32
01.01.18,   8
01.01.18,   12
01.01.18,   77
02.01.18,   99
03.01.18,   78
04.01.18,   89
```

Comment: What would you want as `payment` for days which are not in your existing dataframe? It might help if you can show a sample of your expected output.

Comment: @jpp updated the question

Comment: `df[(df.date >= "01.01.18") & (df.date <= "31.01.18")]`?

Comment: You can look at the marked duplicate. Note that `.ix` has been depreciated, so use `.loc`.

Comment: @jpp well, every single answer in that question has .ix solution (quite confusing since it was depreciated), may be it worth updating the question or create another one, like this.

Comment: @user40, When I have some time, I'll go through them and stick a banner on top :). But for now, I always make sure when I mark as I duplicate I add a comment so users don't get confused. I've also added another recent duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You need:

```
df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df['date'])).loc['2018-01-01':'2018-01-31'].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
        date    payment
0   01.01.18    32
1   01.01.18    8
2   01.01.18    12
3   01.01.18    77
```

You can keep using your original dateformat as well with below code and achive same output:

```
import datetime as dt
start = dt.datetime.strptime('01.01.18', '%d.%m.%y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
end = dt.datetime.strptime('31.01.18', '%d.%m.%y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df['date'])).loc[start:end].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: Thanks, why the output doesn't have values for  02.01.18, 03.01.18, 04.01.18 dates?

Comment: @user40 that's because of `pd.to_datetime()`

Comment: so how do I include those values as well? They are within the range '2018-01-01':'2018-01-31'

Comment: @user40, good point. See the edit.

Comment: what is dt ? thanks

Comment: It's the alias for `datetime` library. I have included the `import` statement. I hope that clears out your doubt.

Comment: I get 'KeyError: 'date'' error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172100/discussion-between-harv-ipan-and-user40).